# Rule containing only optional rules requires at least one

Tags: java, antlr4

I am facing a similar issue as in this question: [At least one Antlr rule optional part](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66710196/at-least-one-antlr-rule-optional-part)

However my situation is slightly different, I dont have any constant prefix and suffix like in the question above. Namely I have a rule that looks like this:

```
sequence_A: field_A_20? field_A_21R? field_A_28D? field_A_50a? field_A_50a_1? field_A_52a? field_A_51A? field_A_30? field_A_25?;
```

As you can see I have sub rules that are all optional. Basically all the fields might be there or they might not be there. Of course this causes an issue that the rule can match an empty string, and since the rule `sequence_A` will be used with `*` this causes even more problems.

The good thing is, if none of the fields are present then `sequence_A` should also not match, that means at least one of the fields above has to be present for a match. However it can be either of them. Of course like in the question mentioned above I can assert this later in the visitor, however the problem is the grammar itself will be invalid as the rule matches the empty string and is used in a closure so I dont even get to the visitor.

The difficult part is, that there is nothing indicating that `sequence_A` starts, except that a random field of the list is present. Also the order of the fields is important. If they are present, they have to be present in that order.

I am kind of at a loss how to proceed with this. Is this even possible with antlr?

There is a solution, but I would like to avoid it. I am already using a code generator to generate the grammar, so I would in theory be able to generate all variations where I `|` together all variations where just one of the fields is mandatory, but I am hoping that there is an easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of the order being significant and the fact the `sequence_A` can appear zero-or-more times, this is probably the way to go:

```
sequence_A: field_A_20 field_A_21R? field_A_28D? field_A_50a? field_A_50a_1? field_A_52a? field_A_51A? field_A_30? field_A_25?;
```

If `sequence_A` matches then it must always start with `field_A_20`, so you can make this non-optional and have solved the problems with empty string matching and a kleene rule matching such an empty string rule.

### Update

It wasn't clear to me that you also might need sub parts. In that case I'd go this way:

```
sequence_A:
    field_A_20 field_A_21R? field_A_28D? field_A_50a? field_A_50a_1? field_A_52a? field_A_51A? field_A_30? field_A_25?
    | field_A_21R field_A_28D? field_A_50a? field_A_50a_1? field_A_52a? field_A_51A? field_A_30? field_A_25?
    | field_A_28D field_A_50a? field_A_50a_1? field_A_52a? field_A_51A? field_A_30? field_A_25?
    | field_A_50a field_A_50a_1? field_A_52a? field_A_51A? field_A_30? field_A_25?
    | field_A_50a_1 field_A_52a? field_A_51A? field_A_30? field_A_25?
    | field_A_52a field_A_51A? field_A_30? field_A_25?
    | field_A_51A field_A_30? field_A_25?
    | field_A_30 field_A_25?
    | field_A_25
;
```

Not particularly elegant, but at least doesn't need platform action code (if that counts for you at all). You can give all alternatives a label and will have an easy time in your visitor.

Comment: Unfortunately it can start with any of them, but if it starts - lets say - with 28D only 50a, 50a_1, 52a, 51A, 30 and 25 can follow, due to ordering. if it were 28D and then 20, it would be 2 sequence As, one containing 28D, one containing 20. Its a bit of a tricky thing.

Comment: I like your edit, I have implemented so far the brute force attempted to just generate the cross product of all fields with always one mandatory. It works, but its slow. Your version is correct, I dont have to repeat all the previous fields as optional, since if they would be present it would take a previous match already. Gonna give it a try tomorrow!

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, your `sequenceA` rule has to have at least one of the sub-rules, and they have to be in the prescribed order.

(untested code)

You could add the following method that will evaluate whether a given context has at least One non-null child node.

```
@parser::members {
    boolean atLeastOne(ParserRuleContext ctx) {
        return ctx.children.stream().anyMatch((c) -> {
            return c != null;
        });
    }
}
```

Then, use it as predicate for your "all are optional" rule:

```
sequence_A: 
  field_A_20? 
  field_A_21R? 
  field_A_28D? 
  field_A_50a? 
  field_A_50a_1? 
  field_A_52a? 
  field_A_51A? 
  field_A_30? 
  field_A_25?
  {atLeastOne(_localctx)}?
;
```

Comment: That is currently my brute force attempt since the whole grammar is generated. i think there is no alternative that works with the features of antlr :)

Comment: (sorry... was modifying answer as you were commenting).   I believe this will accomplish the same thing (but much more elegantly)

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
sequence_A: (
   field_A_20 |
   field_A_21R | 
   field_A_28D | 
   field_A_50a | 
   field_A_50a_1 |
   field_A_52a | 
   field_A_51A  |  
   field_A_30 | 
   field_A_25
  )+;
```

This will allow a match of multiple instances of any alternative, but you can add that semantic check using a visitor.  The important thing is getting a parse tree that accurately reflects the proper interpretation of the input stream.  Then you can check semantic issues like duplicates.

Comment: This is an option, but will make the visitor quite tricky. Sequence A can appear multiple times, and lets say I have field 28D followed by field 20. This should resolve to two sequences A, since the order is imporant, one with just field 28D, one with just field 20. With the | I end up with just one sequence A and have to divide it later in the visitor.